# How to block previous year in JQuery Datepicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

In jquery Datepicker, I won't block the previous year which means I only select the current year.
Ex: Current year is now 2020 but in jquery Datepicker, I choose the previous year(2019) also. But I want to Disable the previous year(2019).

Comment: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `minDate` option in the settings of the datepicker and set it to January 1st 2020. [Link to API docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate)